# Storing postgres function results in a record

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm trying to create some sub functions that will be used to create fully configured products for my customer's database system.  One of the functions is to calculate the list price and discounted price of the item based on a set of arguments.  Since different types of items are created by different functions, but the way that the prices are calculated is essentially the same, I want one function that calculates the list price and discounted price for all my different types of items.

My main function (lets call it create_item) is successfully sending arguments to my sub function (lets call it calculate_price) and my sub function is successfully sending back the list price and discounted price in a table.  What I'm having trouble with is how I store those results in a record in the main function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_item(
          integer, 
          integer)
Returns VOID
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$

DECLARE

accessory_price alias for $1;
customer_discount alias for $2;
list_price numeric;
discounted_price numeric;
returnRecord record;

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM calculate_price(accessory_price, customer_discount) INTO returnRecord;

list_price = SELECT list_price FROM returnRecord;
discounted_price = SELECT discounted_price FROM returnRecord;

END;

$BODY$;

----------END OF MAIN FUNCTION

----------BEGINNING OF SUB FUNCTION

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_price(
          integer, 
          integer)
RETURNS TABLE (
      list_price numeric,
      discounted_price numeric) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$

DECLARE

accessory_price alias for $1;
customer_discount alias for $2;
list_price numeric;
discounted_price numeric;

---*** INSERT LOGIC USED TO CALCULATE LIST_PRICE BASED ON VARIABLES
---*** INSERT LOGIC USED TO CALCULATE DISCOUNTED_PRICE BASED ON LIST_PRICE AND VARIABLES

RETURN QUERY SELECT list_price, discounted_price;

END;

$BODY$
```

So far this almost works.  I can check the variables throughout the process by raising notices and everything calculates correctly, but when I try to store the results of calculate_price into the returnRecord I get an error that "the returned results have no place to be stored" or something like that (sorry I can't remember the exact verbiage).  Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must do some change(INTO returnRecord after * and returnRecord.list_price,returnRecord.discounted_price instead select   ) in main function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_item(
      integer, 
      integer)
Returns VOID
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

 AS $BODY$

 DECLARE

  accessory_price alias for $1;
  customer_discount alias for $2;
  list_price numeric;
  discounted_price numeric;
  returnRecord record;

 BEGIN

  SELECT * INTO returnRecord FROM calculate_price(accessory_price, customer_discount);

 list_price = returnRecord.list_price;
 discounted_price = returnRecord.discounted_price;

END;

$BODY$;
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was driving me nuts.